# how to show iframe with JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I make a simple project where I would like show iframe with method `.show()` of jQuery, I show on main site of jQuery and I try to do this:

```js
$(function() {
  // run the currently selected effect
  function runEffect() {
    // get effect type from
    var selectedEffect = $( "#effectTypes" ).val();

    // most effect types need no options passed by default
    var options = {};
    // some effects have required parameters
    if ( selectedEffect === "scale" ) {
      options = { percent: 100 };
    } else if ( selectedEffect === "size" ) {
      options = { to: { width: 280, height: 185 } };
    }

    // run the effect
    $( "#effect" ).show( "blind", options, 500, callback );
  };

  //callback function to bring a hidden box back
  function callback() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $( "#effect:visible" ).removeAttr( "style" ).fadeOut();
    }, 1000 );
  };

  // set effect from select menu value
  $( "#button" ).click(function() {
    runEffect();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div align="center"><b>Sorveglianza RaspiCam</b></div>

<div id="effect" class="sorv">
  <iframe src='http://www.sito.it' width='1024' height='640'></iframe>
</div>

<button id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Run Effect</button>
```

But the button don't work and iframe is ever visible, where I wrong?
thanks,
Daniel.

Comment: You had some problems in your html. I fixed them  and now it's seems that it work. Isn't?

Comment: @MoshFeu — Are you saying that you edited the question to remove the problem so it is no longer a valid question?

Comment: Yes, if I understand the question, when you click on the `run effect` button the iframe should be fadeout but it doesn't. Now, it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Style sheet link was incorrect.
2- The `$(function()` dose not closed.
the below code should work:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>RaspiCam</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
  $(function() {
    // run the currently selected effect
    function runEffect() {
      // get effect type from
      var selectedEffect = $( "#effectTypes" ).val();

      // most effect types need no options passed by default
      var options = {};
      // some effects have required parameters
      if ( selectedEffect === "scale" ) {
        options = { percent: 100 };
      } else if ( selectedEffect === "size" ) {
        options = { to: { width: 280, height: 185 } };
      }

      // run the effect
      $( "#effect" ).show( "blind", options, 500, callback );
    };

    //callback function to bring a hidden box back
    function callback() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $( "#effect:visible" ).removeAttr( "style" ).fadeOut();
      }, 1000 );
    };

    // set effect from select menu value
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
      runEffect();
    });
  });
  </script>             
    </head>
  <body>
        <div align="center"><b>Sorveglianza RaspiCam</b></div>

        <div id="effect" class="sorv">
           <iframe src='http://www.sito.it' width='1024' height='640'></iframe>
        </div>

        <button id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Run Effect</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i've tried your suggestion, and i thank you, but, this don't work.
When i see the page iframe must be hidden and see if i push the button,
sorry my bad english but i'm italian, i hope you understand.